# GCP GKE Google Kubernetes Engine The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

i am trying GCP and GKE google kubernetes engine.
1-)i am create a cluster
2-)i opened cloud shell and used command "kubectl get nodes"

i get this error:
"The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

how can i solve. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You must have a local Kubernetes config file that is used by `kubectl` to access cluster(s).

Conventionally, the config file is called `config` (YAML) and is found in `${HOME}/.kube/config`.

Google provides a way to generate a config file (and context) for you. To do this run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...`. You'll need to fill in the blanks of the cluster name and probably the project, zone/region etc.:

```sh
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--region=${REGION}
```

After running this command, you should be able to `more ${HOME}/.kube/config` and you should be able to access the cluster using e.g. `kubectl get nodes`.

Comment: You might need to make sure that you allow communication to the controller server as well. If it allows only traffic from X.X.X.X, then you won't be able to access it this way anyway.